# How to make multiple DLL instances able to access each other?

Tags: delphi, dll, loadlibrary

I'm designing a modular software infrastructure from the ground up, where different DLL's hold different business logic, and application logic. Each DLL has its own mechanism of initialization / uninitialization through common DLL calls.

Let's say I have a host application which uses these various different DLL's. All those DLL's are loaded and initialized by the host application via `LoadLibrary`. When one DLL initializes, it instantiates some internal global variables. Can I use another DLL to connect to this one and access the same instance without routing through the host? Surely calling `LoadLibrary` from within the other DLL would create another instance, and calling the DLL directly would also not be initialized / instantiated?

How do I access instantiated data from one DLL to another which were initialized by the same host application?

For example, a database connection. I encapsulate an ADO connection inside one DLL with methods of fetching / executing, etc. I would like one DLL to use the same connection which was instantiated from the host app in this DB DLL.

Comment: *.. would create another instance ..* - Not if you don't free the library. After the executable loaded the library, *other* libraries will use the *instance* that is already mapped to the executable's address space. You can export global data through exported functions to other libraries and the executable, it won't get initialized again as long as you don't free the library. Libraries do not run on their own, it's really the executable running code in them.

Comment: Just to clarify: A new executable program that loads an already loaded DLL will re-use the same CODE but not the same DATA (unless it is declared in a SHARED data segment - something Delphi does not allow to define).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries (DLL modules) are shared within a process. The global variables of a library have a single instance. When you call LoadLibrary on a DLL that is already loaded, you are returned a module handle to the already loaded module. A single DLL can be loaded once only into a process.

So, it's perfectly fine for you to use LoadLibrary and then call that library's functions.

As an alternative you could use GetModuleHandle if you were sure that the library was already loaded. For example, you never need to call LoadLibrary for kernel32 since it's always loaded.